# How to create address of string inline in NASM

Tags: assembly, nasm, low-level

I am a total NASM/ASSEMBLY newbie.

I am writing a compiler (Just for education purposes), in my compiler I translate the source code into assembly and use NASM to compile it to object file and then use a linker to create a executable file.

I am using 64 bit ubuntu.

I want to convert this to assembly

```py
print("Hello World!")
```

One way is to write

```
section .data

message db "Hello World!", 0
messagel equ $-message-1

section .text


   mov rax, 1
   mov rdi, 1
   mov rsi, message
   mov rdx, messagel
   syscall

   
   mov rax, 60
   mov rdi, 0
   syscall
```

But I dont want to store "Hello World!" string forever after the syscall I want it to be gone.

I tried something something like this

```
  mov rax, 1
  mov rdi, 1 
  mov rsi, "Hello World", 0
  mov rdx, 12
```

But it did not work since I have to pass `address` of string in `rsi` not the `string` itself.

So I am wondering is there any way to inline the address of string

Comment: _"But I dont want to store "Hello World!" string forever after the syscall I want it to be gone."_ For what purpose? Are you trying to hide the information, or are you trying to save space?

Comment: You can put it onto the stack but that will take more instruction bytes than simply storing a constant in the data section. Note that `print("Hello World!")` also creates the string in the (read only) data section.

Comment: @Michael No reason, I just thought thats not how compilers should work. But If its okay to use `section .data` I will use that itself

Comment: Well, like Jester said, the string literal will probably end up in the `.rodata` section rather than the `.data` section. But you can't really get around having to store the string _somewhere_, in some form.

Comment: If the data isn't a static constant (e.g. in `.rodata`), you'll have to create it with instructions like mov-immediate64 / push or something similar.  Since there isn't a lot of redundancy in the string you want to create, this will take more bytes of code than it would cost bytes of data.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I use, I based it off of [this routine](http://6502.org/source/io/primm.htm) built into the Commodore 64's KERNAL, and I translated a similar version into 8086 Assembly. Unfortunately I'm not too familiar with 64-bit x86 but the general concept should hopefully be the same:

```
CALL PRIMM
db "Hello World",0

JMP $

PRIMM:
pop ax ;the return address is also the address of the 0th character of the string. So get it into ax
mov si,ax
loop_primm:
mov al,[es:si]  ;assumes es points to code segment. 
;Don't worry about this part, I don't know how segments work on x86-64 (if they even exist)
cmp al,0
jz exit

;I can't remember the syscall for printing characters on dos, I'll update this later. 
;The required interrupt will go here

jmp loop_primm

exit: ;you've incremented si past the terminator and to the rest of your program
push si ;use a "retpoline" to get back to the main program.
ret
```

Comment: If you're going to use a segment override, use `cs:si`.  But fortunately 64-bit mode enforces a flat memory model.  The segment bases are all fixed at 0 (except FS and GS).  In shellcode, you must avoid `call` going forward, because that would involve `00` bytes in the high 3 bytes of the rel32.  That's why the normal idiom is jmp forward (so it can use rel8), then `call` backward to a `pop`.  (Or in x86-64, using `lea rsi, [rel my_str]`, after jumping over it, but that's more total bytes than jmp/call/pop)

Comment: The length is known at assemble time so you don't need to loop over the string data. 
 Also, `push/ret` is not a "retpoline" (there's no trampoline / thunk that you're calling or jumping to), it's just a way to do an absolute `jmp`. (Which is pointless in this case.)  If you wanted to jump to the `jmp $` infinite loop, you could just put a label there and `jmp` to it.